# How to get the text of a section on an HTML page

Tags: html, url

I have a webpage with this section:

```
<section class="post__content">
At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui
blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos
dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate
non provident.                           
</section>
```

I need to get the text from that section.
I tried:
https://www.example.com/quote-of-the-day?d=01/09/2021/#post__content

Comment: "I tried"  - how tried? You would need to grab that on a server if your script is not fromthe same origin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF the text is on the same PAGE as the script

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("section.post__content").textContent
  .replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"") // get rid of trailing newlines, remove if you need them
)
```

```html
<section class="post__content">
At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui
blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos
dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate
non provident.                           
</section>
```

IF the text is on ANOTHER page which is on the same server as where you want to grab it, you can use jQuery or fetch. Here jQuery can parse the page and just grab the section

```
$.get("/quote-of-the-day?d=01/09/2021/ section.post__content",function(data) { console.log(data) })
```

Please note that class is `.post__content` and ID is `#post__content`

If NOT, then you need some server process

Comment: So complicated. Why he should slow down his website with jQuery if he wants to just get the text?

Comment: @RamoFX Please see relevant update. I assumed the text was NOT on the same page as the script

Comment: Oh, okay, sorry for that

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan. The first alternative worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const sectionText = document.querySelector("section.post__content").textContent

console.log(sectionText)
```

You can even create a function that gets an element's text:

```js
const getElementText = selector => {
  return document.querySelector(selector).textContent
}

const sectionText = getElementText("section.post__content")

console.log(sectionText)
```

NOTE: If you have more `section` tags with `post__content` class, then you should use `document.querySelectorAll()` which return an array of all nodes.

Comment: This is assuming it i on the same page as the script!